# there is a great deal more going on

Tags: predicative-complement

I want to know the grammatical rule of *more* in the following context and the meaning of *going on*. Also, why is the verb used in progressive tense?

> "When you look at a tree, you may notice only the branches and leaves. A closer look shows that there is actually a great deal **more** **going on**. Trees provide home to ... "

Source: IELTS Essential words

Comment: *There is more*; *more* is a predicate complement. *Going on* means happening.

Answer (score 1):

To *go on* with no object is a phrasal verb meaning "to be in a state that is 'in progress' or not stopped."

When used directly it often carries an implication of continuing despite difficulty.

> The project goes on.
>
> Life goes on.

*More* is a pronoun here, and *going on* is a post-positive adjectival participial phrase modifying *more* (qualifying *more* by telling what kind of *more*).

*More* is often used as a comparative modifier (It is more cold in here than the other room) but it can also be used as a standalone pronoun, especially when we don't know exactly what the "more of something" is.

Comment: there is a great deal more going on (than what the previous sentence stated)